# Why does elementary not shut down properly?

Tags: release-freya, shutdown

I sometimes have a problem shutting down elementary freya 0.3.2 (running on an early 2008 MacBook). After the system shuts down all devices (modem etc), the output is like this:

> *will now halt
>
> [7128.252276] hub 6-0:1.0 hub_port_status failed (err= -110)
>
> [7128.252427] hub 6-0:1.0 hub_port_status failed (err= -110)

or

> *will now halt
>
> [4591.300273] hub 6-0:1.0 hub_port_status failed (err= -110)
>
> [4591.300249] hub 6-0:1.0 hub_port_status failed (err= -110)

Then it just hangs and I have to turn off the machine using the power button. Any ideas? The problem occurs randomly and I don't know if the numbers in brackets are always the ones I mentioned here, they're just examples.

Comment: If you are still having this problem, can you pls post the output of lspci command. You can also take a look at this post: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5600 and this post: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=140184

Comment: I switched to another computer and Loki in the meantime, but thanks nonetheless!