# Graphics Shattering and power problems on Macbook

Tags: suspend, macbook, shutdown, graphics, user-interface

I've recently installed elementary os (0.3.2) on all my computers and I must congratulate the development team for finally getting most of the UI right. Perhaps even better than my experience with Mac OS X (the highest compliment I can think of).

That being said, there is a graphics problem with my macbook (early-2008). Although the os is performing spectacularly on this laptop, I seem to get graphical artifacts when changing between workspaces, or getting notifications. The artefacts appear as if the frames are shattering. Upon turning off notifications and animations, the problem is less frequent. I suspect that this is a case of obsolete integrated graphics (Intel GMA X3100), but I wanted to be sure, because the system is running fast and there is no lag in graphics as such. I'm unable to capture the shattering in a screenshot.  For the following command: `sudo lshw -c video`

I get this output:

```
      *-display:0             
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:28 memory:d0100000-d01fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:6110(size=8)
```

The other problem I'm facing is regarding shut down and suspend. Sometimes, the laptop does not recover from suspend. Sometimes during shutdown, the laptop gets stuck at the elementary os logo. I'm forced to hard restart the system in both cases.

Any known cause/solution for the problem?

Comment: Do you have a cell phone you could record a video of this "animation" on?

Comment: I've posted this video on youtube: https://youtu.be/fMPKw5EkOew

Comment: Okay two things:

1. Please separate your questions. The Shutdown/Suspend issue is for a another question.

2. The graphics problem is likely due to the intel graphics you are using indeed. There may be a workaround available.

Comment: I have exactly the same problems with my early 2008 MacBook. For the suspend issue see here: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3530/why-does-elementary-not-shut-down-properly - I hope somebody will come up with an answer soon...

Comment: Is is worthwhile changing the desktop from pantheon to mate? I want to figure out whether my graphics driver or my driver is incompetent. If the shattering does not persist in mate then it demonstrates that the driver is fine and my hardware needs something more lightweight. 
Anything wrong with the implication?

Answer (score 1):

I have a laptop the same obsolete GPU.It was having artifacts and I could fix it by running

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
echo -e 'Section "Device"\n Identifier "Intel Graphics"\n Driver "Intel"\n Option "AccelMethod" "sna"\n Option "TearFree" "true"\nEndSection' | sudo tee /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
sudo reboot
```